# Is it possible to use mapkit to create a custom map?

Tags: xcode, function, google-maps, swift, mapkit

Is it possible to use the mapkit with swift without using a map of earth?
Basically what I'm asking, If I created a map of a fictional place, could I use the mapkit functions on it?

Comment: I think Google Maps is based on real places. If you want to use a map of fictional places, Google Maps might not be the best choice for you. But Google Maps can give you some features like polyline drawing, geofence overlay circles and floor plans etc. It really depends on what extra features you want to build or customize on top of the Google Map

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with something like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com) if you want to create custom maps but have a MapKit-like programming experience.